# How to customize border style on Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

How to customize border style on Chart.js

`Chart.js 2.2.1`

By default the border of bars and points is a solid line. If possible, I'd like to draw attention to specific bars or lines by making the border into a dotted or dashed line.

[Going through the docs](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/04-Bar-Chart.md) didn't turn up anything useful. Below is what I thought might work

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var borderColors = ['red','blue','black']
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Black"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3],
            borderColor:borderColors,
            borderWidth:3,
            borderStyle:'dash'//has no effect
        }]
    }
});
```

Here it is [running live](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akAQpr).  How can I make a border dashed?

EDIT: My question is different from [this similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054620/change-chart-js-bar-chart-border-to-dotted-line) for two reasons

1. that solution replaces all bar borders with dashed lines, whereas as I pointed out I'd like to style only specific bars within the dataset
2. that solution is exclusively for bar charts (it overrides the `rectangle.draw` function whereas I mentioned that I'd like to also make point borders dashed (in line charts) for specific points within the dataset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Chart JS Bar Chart Border to Dotted Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054620/change-chart-js-bar-chart-border-to-dotted-line)

Comment: Thanks @GlenDespaux. That solution replaces all bar borders with dashed lines. What I'm trying to do is to draw attention to a specific bar or point (on line charts) by changing just that datapoint's border to dashed

Comment: A solution for Chart.js v3 is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72424830/2358409

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of editing all the chart and the Rectangle as in the *[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054620/change-chart-js-bar-chart-border-to-dotted-line)*, you should do it only for each bar you want to display with dashed lines.

If you take a look at the console (`console.log(myChart)` *provides you a lot of info if you dare go deep in the object*), you will see that every bar is instancied in `myChart.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[`***`x`***`]`, 
***`x`*** being the xth bar of the dataset.

---

Knowing where you should go, you can now edit the `.draw()` method.

Here is a simple function you can use to make it work :

```js
function dashedBorder(chart, dataset, data, dash) {

    // edit the .draw() function
    chart.config.data.datasets[dataset]._meta[0].data[data].draw = function() {
        chart.chart.ctx.setLineDash(dash);
        Chart.elements.Rectangle.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        // put the line style back to the default value
        chart.chart.ctx.setLineDash([1,0]);
    }
}
```

You can see the result in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kewmh8w0/).

Comment: Wow, really cool. Do you think the same general advice would apply to drawing point borders on line charts?  Thank you.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Do you mean replacing the default line of a single dataset by a dashed one ? I guess it would be the same idea

Comment: I was talking about the 2nd part of the OP (#2 in `Edit` section).  I meant would a similar approach work to dash the border of a specific datapoint on the line. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWoLax

Comment: @BeetleJuice I've never touched datapoints on the linechart .. But I think the `pointStyle` attribute can be an image, so can you do almost everything you want :)