# How to make bars dashed in chart js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, bar-chart, react-chartjs

Hello Everyone I am new to chart JS , I need to make bars dashed . I am currenlty using version - "chart.js": "^3.7.0" ,

I need my bars look like [This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Efj4.png)

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: When you work with React, why don't you use chart.js integrations like https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom chart type by extending `Chart.BarController` as explained [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html#extending-existing-chart-types).

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
class DashedBorderBar extends Chart.BarController {
  draw() {
    super.draw(arguments);
    const ctx = this.chart.ctx;
    ctx.save();
    const dataset = this.chart.data.datasets[0];
    ctx.strokeStyle = dataset.dashedBorderColor;
    ctx.lineWidth = dataset.dashedBorderWidth;
    ctx.setLineDash(dataset.borderDash);    
    this.getMeta().data.forEach(d => {      
      ctx.strokeRect(d.x - d.width / 2, d.y, d.width, d.height + ctx.lineWidth);
    });
    ctx.restore();
  }
};
DashedBorderBar.id = 'dashedBorderBar';
DashedBorderBar.defaults = DashedBorderBar.defaults;
Chart.register(DashedBorderBar);

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'dashedBorderBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 45, 40],
      dashedBorderColor: 'blue',
      dashedBorderWidth: 3,
      borderDash: [10, 5]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="120"></canvas>
```

Comment: When I try to use Chart.BarController it prints undefined.